# Create new column to identify the first value >0 across different columns

Tags: r

I have the following data frame

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c(0,0,1,1),col2 = c(1,0,0,3),col2 = c(1,0,0,3))
```

How can I identify the the first value of each value which is greater than 0.
The expected output is like this

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c(0,0,1,1),col2 = c(1,0,0,3),col3 = c(1,0,0,3),col4 = c(1,0,1,1))
```

And I have tried the followings

```
for (i in 1:3){
  df$col4 <- apply(df[,c(0:i)],1,sum)
  if (df$col4>0) 
    break
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df$col4 <- apply(df, 1, function(x) x[which(x>0)[1]])
df[is.na(df$col4),'col4'] <- 0
```

Comment: May I ask if there is a way to count backward, so i can have column 4 as 1,0,2,3 ?

Comment: try `df$col4 <- apply(df, 1, function(x) x[tail(which(x>0),1)])`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `max.col()` for this.

```
df[cbind(1:nrow(df), max.col(df > 0, "first"))]
# [1] 1 0 1 1
```

Comment: Lovely. That is actually what I was aiming for. Full Vectorization

Answer (score 0):

Here is another idea using `mapply`,

```
unlist(mapply(`[`, split(df, 1:nrow(df)), max.col(df>0, ties.method = 'first')))
#1.col2 2.col1 3.col1 4.col1 
#     1      0      1      1
```

Depending on what you need by 'count backward', you can either change `ties.method` to 'last', i.e.

```
unlist(mapply(`[`, split(df, 1:nrow(df)), max.col(df>0, ties.method = 'last')))
#1.col2.1 2.col2.1   3.col1 4.col2.1 
#       1        0        1        3
```

Or reverse the data frame and leave `ties.method` to 'first', i.e.

```
unlist(mapply(`[`, split(rev(df), 1:nrow(df)), max.col(df>0, ties.method = 'first')))
#  1.col2 2.col2.1 3.col2.1 4.col2.1 
#       1        0        0        3
```